# Get data for XmlDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I want to read entire data/all nodes from XmlDocument. I don't want to use InnerXml/OuterXml properties. Any other way to read from XmlDocument ?. Below example I have get data using OuterXml property, but I don't want to use Outerxml.

Ex:

```
     XmlDocument ACTGraphicalXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
     ACTGraphicalXMLDoc.LoadXml(ACTConfigXML);

     StringBuilder ConfigXML = new StringBuilder();
     ConfigXML.Append(ACTGraphicalXMLDoc.OuterXml);
     string ConfigXML2 = ConfigXML.ToString();
```

Comment: If you are working with .NET 3.5 or later i would recommened to use System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.

Comment: Dou you want (a list of) the data or the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
ACTGraphicalXMLDoc.WriteTo(tx);
sw.ToString();
```